# Count the number of items that contain "JJ number" and "JJ alphabet"

Tags: excel, countif

I have a column of data show as below. I would like to count the number of items that contain "`JJ number`", and "`JJ alphabet`", which are 6 and 4. I try to use `countifs` function with the first criteria as " JJ *`` " but then I fail to get the second criteria right by using left, len or `isnumber` function.

This is the partial code that I have been working on:

```
=COUNTIFS(A:A, "JJ *", ...
```

Here is an example of input data:

```
jj 1288
jj 2838
jj 3344
jj 6288
jj 8838
jj 3344
jj fan
jj tsz
jj zch
```

Comment: could u add a extra coulumn? That way u could split the cell and make it easier.

Comment: The data come in this way, so it's difficult to split them apart. I don't have problem setting two formula for JJ number and JJ alphabet though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well here is a table I created which will solve your problem. I took it step by step in the below screenshot but here is one formula which can help you.

Add 2 columns to the right of your table and add the below formula

```
=IF(ISNUMBER(IFERROR(INT(RIGHT([@colName],LEN([@colName])-SEARCH(" ",[@colName]))),"")),1,0)
```

This will return 1 if it is a number and 0 if it is a charecter.
In the next column use the below formula.

```
=IF([@newcolumn]=1,0,1)
```

Change the @colname & @newcolumn to the column name you keep in the table.
@colname is the first column and @newcolumn is the column we added with the formula.

Once you achieve this, a simple sum will get you the result.

[image]

Comment: Hi, thank you for the detailed explanation for the problem, but I am confused by colName and newcolumn. Should I replace colName with A:A and newcolumn with C:C? Assume that A:A is where the original data located, the first formula you provided will place on column B and the second will place on column C.

Comment: Make a table "Cntrl + T", "colname" & "newcolumn" are the headers of the columns.. You can change  "colname" or " newcolumn" to cell A1 etc.

Like in my above image, you see the table headers as "name","space","after space" etc.

Comment: Good to know that! Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

My initial idea was to write

```
 =IFERROR(NUMBERVALUE(MID(A1;4;20));"text")
```

If you put that in the a column you would get the number as a value and the cells with `JJ text` would output `text`. 
After that you can use your `COUNTIF`

Comment: Thanks for your idea, however, when I put the formula into work, the result come out as "text" regardless the referencing cell is `JJ Number` or `JJ text` this is how my excel 2010 accepts it `=IFERROR(NUMBERVALUE(MID(A1,4,20)), "text")`